# linux or unix shortcut command which can be used from and directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have total seven directory at different location where my logs gets stored, I need to create shortcut command in UNIX such that if I type that command anywhere in the UNIX directory it should move to directory.

EG:

/var/opt/t1/logs/20171003  - T1

/var/opt/t2/logs/20171003  - T2

/var/opt/t3/logs/20171003  - T3

/var/opt/t4/logs/20171003  - T4

/var/opt/t5/logs/20171003  - T5

/var/opt/O1/logs/20171003  - O1

/var/opt/O2/logs/20171003  - O2

if i want to go T1 i want i just need to give - T1 in the Unix box and it should go to that folder.

Comment: Start [reading the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html). What you seem to be looking for is called an *alias*. Or if you want to go to the latest subdirectory, you probably want a *function*. Or possibly use aliases to call a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow below 3 steps:

1. "vi ~/.bash_aliases"(Press i to go to insert mode) or you can use any other editor of your choice
2. create alias:
   alias T1='cd /var/opt/t1/logs/20171003'
   alias T2='cd /var/opt/t2/logs/20171003'
   and so on...
3. type following command "source ~/.bashrc" to reflect your change in same terminal or otherwise open new Terminal.

Comment: I would recommend defining *functions*, not aliases (or use a common  function to ease definition of these aliases)

Comment: Do i need to create a new file and then add those code over her ?

Comment: Yes either create new file bash_aliases (easier to maintain aliases in single file) or you can append to bashrc file in home directory of your system.

Answer (score 0):

You could define aliases or functions for your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (probably `bash`, but I recommend [zsh](http://zsh.org/)).

Read the documentation of your shell,  e.g. the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/). You may want to add [aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-alias) or [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions) definitions into [your `~/.bashrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) which you would edit with a [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (I recommend [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), some people prefer [vim](http://vim.org/) and there are many others). You'll better restart your shell afterward.

Read also [about `CDPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#index-CDPATH) and [about `pushd` and `popd`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html#index-pushd).

BTW, I recommend avoiding spaces in file names (prefer the underscore `_`). It makes life easier (you'll need less [quotations](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting)).

Remember that Linux don't have folders but [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)), and that a file can have several names (or none), and is really an [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

BTW, you could use [grep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) and/or [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) or [awk(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html) or [ln(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) wisely (e.g. in your functions or shell scripts).

Comment: I am new to this, so can you please help me in kick starting with the code at least.

Comment: You need to read a little bit. Follow all the links I gave above. SO is not a code writing or script writing service. And there are several ways of doing what you want. Or hire someone to do that job. But it is much better to improve your skills by spending a few hours reading stuff and experimenting.

Comment: the path is till : /var/opt/t3/logs/20171003 that T1 T2 are just for linking them.

Comment: Spend more time reading. Don't forget to restart the shell after edition of `~/.bashrc`. Ask another question if so needed (but give more details in it).